# Coming up with a metric that measures "homophily"?

Tags: image-processing, metric

[I'm not sure if this question goes here on Stats.SE --- please move if not.]

Consider a 2D unit square. I observe N red and M blue balls on the square.

I want to come up with a metric that measures how much the red and blue balls stick together with balls of the same colour. This metric should obtain its maximum value (1?) when all the blue balls are in one cluster, and all the red balls in another cluster. For instance, either all the blue balls could be on the left and the reds on the right, or the blue balls in a circle in the middle and all the red balls in a donut-shape surrounding it.

The metric should obtain its minimum value (0?) when both the red and blue balls are "maximally scattered": uniformly distributed over {[0,1], [0,1]}. with the caveat that no two balls can occupy the same location.

The metric should take intermediate values when there are several mid-size clusters, or some dispersion.

Additionally, the metric should be invariant to the scale of red and blue balls. That is, the value the metric gives should not change if I double both N and M.

---

How would I go about doing this?

My first intuition is: for every ball, count the number of k-nearest neighbours that are the same colour as that ball, and sum the counts. A highly clustered distribution will have high scores, and a scattered distribution low scores. But it's not clear if the invariant I want is fulfilled. I also am not sure whether this procedure would return a minimum value when the red and blue balls are "maximally scattered".

Comment: Your question is missing some details. You mention neighbours, but you probably mean *nearest* neighbours, as uniformly distributed balls could have everyone as their neighbours, unless three balls fall on a line. Speaking of nearest neighbours, this is a model, and once you start using a model this question becomes much easier to answer. You could simply use a surrogate for misclassification by a model as a measure of how well separated classes are. Is this what you want to do? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Thank you for the comments. I indeed mean k-nearest neighbours, but perhaps other approaches would be better. Have updated the question to clarify. Could you elaborate what you mean by a "surrogate for misclassification"? Feel free to write up an answer ;)

Comment: I think the *coefficient of overlapping* might be a candidate for your measure. [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947305000290) paper explains the measure. The generalization to 2-dimensional densities would be straightforward and it would be able to capture the "blue-in-the-middle and red-as-donut" kind of pattern. As you are looking for homophily, you could use $1 - \text{OVL}(f,g)$, where $f$ and $g$ are, respectively, the densities of the red and blue balls.